# Drawing lines between two points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, excel, polygon-creation

I have an Excel (Fig) which has both `"X"` & `"Y"` in projected coordinates (WGS84/UTM). Is it possible to draw lines between the `"X"` & `"Y"`in QGIS?

I've tried to create points based on **X,From_y** and **X,To_y**. I've created two points by just loading them using add delimiter layer (pasted To_Y below From_Y and loaded it). Then tried with Points 2 paths. But it didn't work out.

Anyone know how to fix this ?

All i need is traverse line between the points

[image]

This is what i am looking for. I've coordinates(X1, a1 and X1, a2) for n number of points which has to be connected by a vertical line

[image]

Comment: So where you've got `x1` and `a1` and `a2` you've got actual numbers in your spreadsheet? And the X coordinate is the same for `from` and `to`? So the lines are vertical? Not clear.

Comment: @Spacedman yes. It has to be a vertical line. I've just edited the question & added an image with respect to this.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

The quickest way to do this with a single line would be using the QuickWKT plugin; you can then right-click and Save As to any format you need.

Let's say your two points are in UTM Zone 36S, and here are listed as x (easting), y (northing):

1. 151930,9593414
2. 184802,9587212

The WKT format for a line is:

```
SRID=SRID;LINESTRING (x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3, ...)
```

Thus, for the example above:

```
SRID=32736;LINESTRING (151930 9593414, 184802 9587212)
```

Pasted into the QuickWKT plugin text box:

[image]

For larger sets of data, you can make an Excel table into a geographic data type by building that WKT string into a column, i.e. (where A2-D2 contain two sets of XY coords):

```
=CONCATENATE("SRID=32736;LINESTRING (",A2, " ", B2, ",", C2, " ", D2, ")")
```

You can save from Excel as a CSV and then use the add delimited text in QGIS (with "watch file" selected to keep it updated).

Comment: It works great for an area. But my requirement is a bit different. I've edited the question & added an image. Pls  have a look.

Comment: The formula for the Excel table is nearly the same, just replace C2 by A2 to get a vertical line.

Comment: @AndreJoost Yep. It has successfully drawn the lines. But   there has been an issue with the coordinate system.

This is the formula which i've used 

SRID=32643;LINESTRING (332950 2293660,332950 2296680)

The coordinate system is 32643: WGS84/UTM 43N. But the loaded wkt file (even though it has lines) is out of range. I've checked "Enable on the fly CRS...". But still it's the same.

Comment: Under `Settings-> Options`, CRS tab, CRS for new layers, check `Prompt for CRS`. Then you will be asked for the CRS during import. It looks like the plugin does not set the CRS correctly from your input, but uses a default of EPSG:4326.